# How to change linespacing of TextArea in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to change the lineSpacing(line height) of TextArea,how is that possible,CSS didn't help, i tried the following codes:

```
    -fx-line-height: 4px;
    -fx-line-spacing: 4px;
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX adding line spacing to text-area

```
.text-area {
     -fx-font-family: Helvetica;
     -fx-text-fill: rgb(33, 33, 33);
     -fx-font-size: 13px;
}

.text-area .text {
     -fx-line-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Remember to create the css for the textarea only else the css will be applied to any text object be it Label text or TextArea text or even ComboBox text.